# Q: forEach in java

Tags: java, foreach

Are these two the same thing? What would I have to do if I couldn't use a forEach?

```
public void adiciona(List<Faixa> fs) {
    fs.forEach(f -> { this.faixas.add(f.clone()); });
}

public void adicionar(List<Faixa> fs){
    for (Faixa f : this.faixas) {
        fs.add(f.clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one is adding clones from `fs` to `this.faixas`. The second one is adding clones from `this.faixas` to `fs`. Not the same thing at all.

Comment: @khelwood Got really confused for some reason but yeah i can see why it's not the same now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't the same. Change the second from

```
for(Faixa f : this.faixas){
    fs.add(f.clone());
}
```

to something like

```
for (Faixa f : fs) {
    this.faixas.add(f.clone());
}
```

You're currently adding to the passed in `List` (instead of adding to the local `List`).

Comment: Or change the first one. You don't know which one was the intended result.

Comment: @Andreas **Maybe**. I interpret *What would I have to do if I couldn't use a forEach?* as meaning the first is *correct*.